# Is SQLite the most appropriate thing to use for an embedded database?

Tags: java, sqlite, h2

I need to build a Java application that I will install on a Linux server.

When people will install they just would need to install this application, launch it, and nothing more. But we have some data to save.

- I said no to MySQL, because it needs a server.
- I said no to XML because there will be really a lot of data to save and manipulate.

So I'm looking at SQLite which is the best I think. Indeed (stop me if i'm wrong), SQLite doesn't need any server? (just install the final application and SQLite works fine in my application?)

Then I checked at http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers and I'm really a little bit confused.

- What is the difference between a Wrapper and a Driver?
- Plus I see there exists  a "pure java implementation": SQLJet is it more or less optimized?
- Finally what would you use in my situation?

Comment: Also see HSQLDB and other embededn Java dbs

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Another database to consider is [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).   It is an embedded database engine completely written in Java so you have the benefit of full unicode (16 bit) character support that Sqlite does *not* have.  Other embedded databases are [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) and [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/).

> sqlite doesnt need any requirement on the server ?

Correct.  It does not.  Neither does H2.

> just install the final application and sqlite works fine in my application ?

Correct.  As long as you include Sqlite or H2 in your WAR (or unpack it into your jar), it will work fine.

> What is the difference between a Wrapper and a Driver ?

Depends on the usage.  I think Sqlite is talking about the fact that when you use the JDBC driver for Sqlite, it is actually a wrapping of the Sqlite C native libraries inside the driver. Typically the JDBC driver talks to a remote database.

H2 also is that way with the "driver" actually doing the database operations just that it was written in Java so you don't need the C wrapper.

> Plus I see there exists a "pure java implementation" : SQLJet is it more or less optimized?

This is the first I've heard of Sqljet so I'm not sure.  The [Xerial Sqlite driver](http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC) is what I've used and it's performance seems to be good.

> Finally what would you use in my situation?

I'd use H2 myself for the native Java features.

Comment: "The Xerial driver actually is simulating the Sqlite C code in a little VM -- strange but it seems to work well" - *really*? As far as i can tell, it isn't doing that now. Was that how it worked when you wrote that?

Comment: I'm not sure where I got that @TomAnderson but I can't find anything that references it so maybe I was suffering from a head wound at the time.  I've edited that section.  Thanks for the pushback.

Comment: Oh, that's a shame. I was hoping they had some amazing implementation in the past!

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes SQLite doesn't require a server.
2. One very simple solution for development is using SQLLite by embedding it in your source code, with a little stub data.  You can then commit your database to your version control system (i.e. I use github, its super easy to do this) as a single file.  This is, obviously, not a good production method, but it is a good way to create a single development version.
3. A Wrapper is a program which facades another program by allowing you to access its functionality through a different interface.  For example, eclipse "wraps" many java programs that we use in everyday development for us in a convenient GUI. Whereas a Driver is a program that is needed to launch an existing application.  For example, in a java application, we might have a main class that can be thought of as a Driver for entry point to the application.