# Searching for a Java embeded database framework/engine

Tags: java, database, frameworks

I'm trying to develop a small Java application using a database. I don't want to use any external database source like postgreSQL.

Can anyone recommend a good embedded persistent database engine, allowing me to create and query tables and store data?

Jetty allows developers to integrate a webserver in a Java application. Does a similar engine exist for databases?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is SQLite the most appropriate thing to use for an embedded database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639256/is-sqlite-the-most-appropriate-thing-to-use-for-an-embedded-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaDB is already provided by Oracle in Java. It is the Oracle packaged version of Apache Derby, an open-source embedded db from Apache.
You can use it without any need to add an external library. 
Look at here for details:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/faqs-jsp-156714.html

Answer (score 0):

You may use H2

- Very fast, open source, JDBC API
- Embedded and server modes; in-memory databases
- Browser based Console application
- Small footprint: around 1.5 MB jar file size

It's a very practical tool. You can find it [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)